# class declaration for ruby

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

im new to ruby and rails.

in RoR3 a controller inherits from the `ActionController::Base`

```
request.env["SERVER_ADDR"]
```

so request is a method in Base class (that is inside the ActionController module)?

what is `env` then and `["SERVER_ADDR"]`?

would be great if someone could make a little code example...that would be very helpful to understand!

thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> ```
> request.env["SERVER_ADDR"]
> ```

1. `request` is *either*

   a. dereferencing the local variable `request` *or*

   b. sending the message `:request` with no arguments to the implicit receiver `self`,
2. `env` is sending the message `:env` with no arguments to the object obtained by dereferencing `request` or the object returned in response to sending the message `:request` to `self` in step 2,
3. `["SERVER_ADDR"]` is sending the message `:[]` with the argument `"SERVER_ADDR"` to the object returned in response to sending the message `:env` in step 2 and
4. `"SERVER_ADDR"` is a string literal.

You could more explicitly write it like this:

```
self.request.env.[]("SERVER_ADDR")
```

or even more explicit like this:

```
self.request().env().[]("SERVER_ADDR")
```

and even full out:

```
self.send(:request).send(:env).send(:[], "SERVER_ADDR")
```

Answer (score 1):

`request.env["SERVER_ADDR"]` can also be written as `request().env()["SERVER_ADDR"]`. So `env` is a method that is called without arguments on the object returned by `request()` and then you call `[]` on the object returned by that with the argument `"SERVER_ADDR"`.

Comment: but why dont u have a dot after env()...request().env().["SERVER_ADDR"]

Comment: Because `foo[bar]` is nicer to read and write than `foo.[bar]`, so the creators of ruby decided that the syntax to call `[]` should be the former.